# Subversion update all working copies under common parent directory

Tags: bash, svn, repository, svn-update

I am working on a number of projects simultaneously. Each project has a Subversion repository. The repositories are not all hosted on the same server. When I start my day, I find myself having to do an `svn update` for each of the individual projects.

My local working copies are all stored under one parent directory *Projects*.

My question: Is there a command that can be issued from the *Projects* directory that will search for working copies among the descendants in the file system and issue an `svn update` command for each of them?

I'm on Ubuntu with Subversion version 1.7.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cd to Projects and then:

```
svn up `ls -d ./*`
```

(note those are backticks, not single quotes.)

svn will happily skip non-svn dirs.
You could add an alias in your `.bashrc`

```
alias up-svn='svn up `ls -d ./*`'
```

Comment: What does the `ls -d ./*` portion do exactly?

Comment: the `-d` prevents recursive listing of dirs.  from the manual: "Directories are listed as plain files (not searched recursively)."

Comment: it does not matter if the projects are on the same server, right? I mean: what if yes? is there any better way? (I know that works perfectly, I'm just thinking about something simpler)

Answer (score 2):

You could just write

```
svn update *
```

That's it... Subversion will automatically recognize the working copies and do the update

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion similar to @thekbb answer

```
svn up `find ~/svn -maxdepth 3 -type d`
```

Explanation:
'~/svn' is my directory all checked out repositories are in
'-maxdepth 3' some repositories are nested (3 levels deep)
e.g. companyname/projectname/branch
'-type d' only directories

Answer (score -1):

no, but you can easily write a script/batch file that calls "svn update" on each subdirectory.